# usage of Apache ignite as Key value data store

Tags: ignite

I am newbie to Apache Ignite. We are trying to explore Ignite as key value DB to be replaced with our existing Berkely DB in application.

Currently, Bekley DB is embedded in the application and db container operations are performed using Berkely DB apis , similar functionalities we would need for Ignite.

The idea is to replace berkley db apis to Ignite apis to use Ignite as key value DB.
I could not find any docs for the usage of ignite libraries to be used in the application.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a comprehensive documentation on data manipulation here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-grid

Also you can find some examples of usage of Ignite API at the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheApiExample.java